# erlang's EXIT and DOWN signal

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, exit, erlang-supervisor

The following code is also from `rabbitmq's supervisor2.erl`. The code's function is to kill supervisor's children, by for every child:

1. monitor child send an trappable exit signal
2. start timer
3. if timer's arrive, send an untrappable exit signal (kill).

My question about `EXIT and DOWN signal.`

If the child doesn't trap the exit signal, the supervisor will receive 2 signal, first is `exit` signal, and then is `DOWN` signal, is it right? Is the signal sequence is strictly guaranteed?

If the child traps the `exit` signal, the supervisor will receive only 1 signal, just `down` signal, is it right?

```
terminate_simple_children(Child, Dynamics, SupName) ->
    Pids = dict:fold(fun (Pid, _Args, Pids) ->
                         erlang:monitor(process, Pid),
                         unlink(Pid),
                         exit(Pid, child_exit_reason(Child)),
                         [Pid | Pids]
                     end, [], Dynamics),
    TimeoutMsg = {timeout, make_ref()},
    TRef = timeout_start(Child, TimeoutMsg),
    {Replies, Timedout} =
        lists:foldl(
          fun (_Pid, {Replies, Timedout}) ->
                  {Reply, Timedout1} =
                      receive
                          TimeoutMsg ->
                              Remaining = Pids -- [P || {P, _} <- Replies],
                              [exit(P, kill) || P <- Remaining],
                              receive {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, Reason} ->
                                      {{error, Reason}, true}
                              end;
                          {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, Reason} ->
                              {child_res(Child, Reason, Timedout), Timedout};
                          {'EXIT', Pid, Reason} -> %%<==== strict signal, first EXIT, then DOWN.
                              receive {'DOWN', _MRef, process, Pid, _} ->
                                      {{error, Reason}, Timedout}
                              end
                      end,
                  {[{Pid, Reply} | Replies], Timedout1}
          end, {[], false}, Pids),
    timeout_stop(Child, TRef, TimeoutMsg, Timedout),
    ReportError = shutdown_error_reporter(SupName),
    [case Reply of
         {_Pid, ok}         -> ok;
         {Pid,  {error, R}} -> ReportError(R, Child#child{pid = Pid})
     end || Reply <- Replies],
    ok.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you are confusing here:

- First, the child is the one trapping exits, but you are looking at the supervisor code. What the child does with exit signals does not directly affect the supervisor.
- the `kill` exit signal *cannot* be trapped. It always kills the child.

The `supervisor2` has a monitor on the child. This means it is guaranteed to get a `'DOWN'` message and this code is concerned about getting that kind of message. If `supervisor2` is also trapping exits, it will get the `'EXIT'` message in addition.

Comment: For your last paragraph, are you sure why 'DOWN' signal will follow 'EXIT' signal? Why not 'EXIT' signal follows 'DOWN' signal? Why? I have made a mark in the above code, it shows the strict signal sequence.